# How to (better) check for element existence within multidimensional array?

Tags: ruby

How do I avoid doing this?

```
if boolean_array[day] && boolean_array[day][slot] && boolean_array[day][slot].zero?
  # boolean_array[day][slot] element exists
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you want an `andand` method. You can then do `if boolean_array[day].andand[slot].andand.zero?`.

Raganwald has [one popular implementation](http://github.com/raganwald/andand).

Comment: Looks like the answer. Mind waiting to see if anybody else has some other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I like [Chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50742/chuck)'s [`andand`](http://github.com/raganwald/andand). I suppose you could also use the low-priority `and` to do it in plain Ruby, at least there would be no parens:

```
>> day = slot = 1; boolean_array = [[], [1,2]]

>> if t = boolean_array[day] and t = t[slot] and t = t.class
>>   puts t
>> end
Fixnum
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use an inline rescue:

```
boolean_array[day][slot].zero? rescue nil
```

Answer (score 0):

if possible, initialize the days and that way you can do the check for boolean_array[day][slot].nil?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without additional gems. Depending on what you have as the value, change `to_i` to `to_f`, etc.

```
if boolean_array[day].to_a[slot].to_i.zero?
  # boolean_array[day][slot] element exists
end
```